# Angular form(s) across multiple tabs, single $pristine/$dirty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

I have [read](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform.FormController) and understood the use of a forms $pristine/$dirty property to detect changes to a form's data.

However, in trying to keep my UI friendly, I have split my various data fields over a number of tabs (I'm using [angular-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)). As far as I can tell I have to create a separate 
'form' element for each tab and use a controller to test across all the tabs' $pristine states in order to determine the overall pristinity (is that a word?).

i.e.

```
<tab>
   <form name="a">...</form>
</tab>
<tab>
   <form name="b">...</form>
</tab>
```

which means I have to test  a.$pristine && b.$pristine to determine the overall pristinity. This becomes laborious when there are many tabs involved.

I have tried

```
<form name="allForm">
   <tab>..</tab>
   <tab>..</tab>
   <tab>..</tab>
</form>
```

but this doesnt work. I guess the  element breaks the form's 'unity'.

Any ideas on how to get a single $pristine (or $dirty) propoerty for a multi-tabbed tabset ?

Comment: This maybe breaking because of new  scope being created in the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/QqBYR/

A change, compared to yours (unless it was a typo) is that the `<form>` actually *wraps* the *entire* `<tabset>`:

```
<form name="theForm">
    <tabset>
        <tab>
            <input ng-model="..." />
        </tab>
        ...
    </tabset>
</form>
```